# Are there any dependencies for UI Automation?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I have a Windows application which captures the details from screen based on the configuration. I am using UI Automation to capture the details from the screen. Everything works fine on the developer's machine where Visual Studio is installed. When I run the same application on another system where we have only .NET Framework 4.5 installed, it started behaving strangely, and it's not able to detect the child element.

My question is why it works fine on the developer's machine where Visual Studio and .NET Framework are installed. What's the difference? Is there anything we are missing as far as prerequisites? Any dependencies of UI Automation or any library we are missing..?

Thanks in advance - please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a known bug in .NET wrapper around native UIAutomationCore.dll (yes, its core is not a .NET). And it's included into WinVista+ (.NET Framework also adds it even to WinXP).

Here is a [C# example](https://github.com/billagee/test-polyglot/tree/master/printDesktopUiaElementName/ms-ui-automation-com-api/csharp) how to use native COM API (`UIAutomationCore.dll`) from C#. Just copying the code here:

```
using System;
using interop.UIAutomationCore;

namespace PrintDesktopUiaElementNameViaCom
{
    class PrintDesktopUiaElementNameViaComProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Instantiate the UIA object:
            IUIAutomation _automation = new CUIAutomation();
            // Get the root element
            IUIAutomationElement rootElement = _automation.GetRootElement();
            // Get its name
            string rootName = rootElement.CurrentName;
            Console.WriteLine(
                "The root automation element's name should be 'Desktop'.");
            Console.WriteLine("The actual value is: '{0}'", rootName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI I got this working using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Interop.UIAutomationClient/ and "using Interop.UIAutomationClient"

Answer (score 0):

Yeah at last after doing day's reading, i came to know the solution is that der is no dependency on Visual studio.

This behavior is due to lack of privileges to the application. so to overcome this behavior we have to get signed our application and one more thing its very important thing is place your executable file in Program Files

Reference Links : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671610(v=vs.85).aspx